# I have the following error what should I do?

Tags: magento2.3, plugin

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class Zend_Cache_Backend_File not found in /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Cache.php:153

Comment: try this first `var/cache` and `var/view_preprocessed` folder remove and second run `composer update` and `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`